# How to dynamically show the contents of three textareas into a common textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show the contents of three textareas in a common textarea. Whatever I type in the textareas that should appear simultaneously inside the common textarea.

I have tried doing this by using the jquery `keyup()` method but that is only partially helpful. Whatever I am writing in a particular textarea (among the first three textareas) is appearing in the common textarea but the problem is - as I start writing in the next textarea, the previous written text is getting deleted from the common textarea and it is only showing the text of current textarea.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="rmks4.1" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area1"></textarea>
<textarea name="rmks4.2" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area2"></textarea>
<textarea name="rmks4.3" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area3"></textarea>
<textarea name="remarks" class="output"></textarea>



<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txt_area1").keyup(function() {
      // Getting the current value of textarea
      var currentText = $(this).val();

      // Setting the Div content
      $(".output").text(currentText);
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txt_area2").keyup(function() {
      // Getting the current value of textarea
      var currentText = $(this).val();

      // Setting the Div content
      $(".output").text(currentText);
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txt_area3").keyup(function() {
      // Getting the current value of textarea
      var currentText = $(this).val();

      // Setting the Div content
      $(".output").text(currentText);
    });
  });
</script>
```

I want whatever I type in the three textareas to be displayed 
pointwise in the common textarea.

I am new to HTML and javascript, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Being *new to JS* and then still starting with jQuery in 2019 imo is a very bad idea. These days, almost everyone is trying to get rid of any jQuery dependencies. I strongly advise to focus on native vanilla Javascript - **learning jQuery will not help you at all on your way to later using frameworks like Angular or Vue, or libraries like React.** Rather, it will do the opposite and place misconceptions in your head, which jQuery does for convenience, which you will then have to re-learn.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance @connexo ,will definitely follow.

Comment: @connexo, what use of learning modern fancy frameworks if you've got a huge project on support full of jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this.

Here I added a common class to the first 3 textarea. using that class in keyup event I got the values and appended it as the output textarea value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".txtar").keyup(function(){
    // Getting the current value of textarea
      var txt1 = $('#txt_area1').val();
      var txt2 = $('#txt_area2').val();
      var txt3 = $('#txt_area3').val();
      txt1 = (txt1)?txt1 + "\n":'';
      txt2 = (txt2)?txt2 + "\n":'';
      txt3 = (txt3)?txt3 + "\n":'';
      // Setting the Div content
      $(".output").val(txt1 + txt2 + txt3);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  name="rmks4.1" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area1" class="txtar"></textarea>
<textarea  name="rmks4.2" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area2" class="txtar"></textarea>               
<textarea  name="rmks4.3" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area3" class="txtar"></textarea>
<textarea name="remarks" class="output" cols="28" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: No need for a class: `$('textarea[name^=rmks]')`.

Comment: yes, but he said he is new for JS. so this answer will be easy for understanding..

Comment: There is a little problem - If I only write in the first and the third textarea, there is a gap between the written text in the common textarea (due to newline).I want the points should come one after the other.

Comment: @AkashMandal code updated. check now

Answer (score 1):

Again, this is **very** easy to do using the native DOM API. No need for jQuery here.

```js
const textareas = [...document.querySelectorAll('textarea[name^=rmks]')];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  for (const textarea of textareas) {
    textarea.addEventListener('input', () => {
      remarks.value = textareas.reduce((acc, val)=> acc + (val.value ? val.value + '\n' : ''), '');
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea name="rmks4.1" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area1"></textarea>
<textarea name="rmks4.2" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area2"></textarea>               
<textarea name="rmks4.3" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area3"></textarea>
<textarea name="remarks" id="remarks" class="output"></textarea>
```

Here's a version that does it for dynamically added textareas as well, using a *delegate listener*:

```js
document.addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
  if (evt.target.matches('textarea[name^=rmks]')) {
    const textareas = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('textarea[name^=rmks]'));
    remarks.value = textareas.reduce((acc, val)=> acc + (val.value ? val.value + '\n' : ''), '');
  }
})

window.setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.innerHTML = `<textarea name="rmks4.1" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area1"></textarea>
<textarea name="rmks4.2" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area2"></textarea>               
<textarea name="rmks4.3" cols="28" rows="5" id="txt_area3"></textarea>
<textarea name="remarks" id="remarks" class="output"></textarea>`
}, 2000);
```